# Rodrigues Rotation of a set of points relative to a vector

Tags: python, vector, rotation, euler-angles

I have a set of points, two of which I am using to designate my desired vector of rotation.

For example, let:

```
x1 = [1,1,1]
x2 = [2,3,1]
```

My desired rotation vector is:

```
x2 - x1 = [1,2,0]
```

I am then trying to rotate a series of 3D points relative to this rotation by a Rodrigues rotation, with my metho being:

```
def rodriguesRotation(vi, k, theta):
    # Accepts vector and returns rotated vector.
    vRotated = (vi * cos(theta)) + ((np.cross(vi, k)) * sin(theta) ) + (k * (np.dot(k, vi)) * (1 - cos(theta)) )
    return vRotated
```

Where `vi` is my unrotated vector, `k` is my desired rotation vector, and `theta` is my Euler angle of rotation. However, this is producing some strange results - I'm not sure if in Python I have to designate my unit vectors for this to work properly, and I believe the reason it is not working is simply because my `k` is a 'point' and not a vector. Any advice?

Comment: quaternion rotation is equivalent and has many example implementations

Answer (score 0):

Your cross product term is reversed. The formula gives it as cross(k,vi).